# Transform Object Will Not Work When Mouse Is Moving Too Fast

Tags: three.js

I wrote a control to transform the object, but when I move the mouse too fast, it will not work.

How can I fix this?

Here is my code: https://jsbin.com/vajunal/edit?html,output

Here is the main code:

```
    var a = 2 * x / this.canvas.width - 1;
    var b = 1 - 2 * y / this.canvas.height;
    this.raycaster.setFromCamera(new THREE.Vector2(a, b), this.camera);
    const intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObject(this.helpPlane);
    if (intersects.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    var pos = intersects[0].point;
    this.helpPlane.position.set(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z)
    this.object.position.set(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because the mouse leaves the "helper plane" between two mousemove events. In order to catch any motion of the mouse, you'd need to make that helper-plane infinitely large. One solution could be to use a `THREE.Plane` instead of the plane-mesh to compute the mouse-position in world-space. See this codepen for an example how to do that: https://codepen.io/usefulthink/pen/XqYqRL (some more documentation there).

In short, this is the procedure:

```
// --- somewhere outside:
const ray = new THREE.Ray();
const target = new THREE.Vector3();
const xzPlane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), 0);

// --- mousemove-handler:
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mousemove", ev => {
  const { offsetWidth: w, offsetHeight: h } = ev.target;
  mouse.x = 2 * ev.clientX / w - 1;
  mouse.y = 1 - 2 * ev.clientY / h;
});

// --- in the animation-loop:
// Compute the ray from the camera through the cursor-position and intersect
// with the xz-plane.
ray.origin.setFromMatrixPosition(camera.matrixWorld);
ray.direction.set(mouse.x, mouse.y, 0.5).unproject(camera);
ray.direction.sub(ray.origin).normalize();

ray.intersectPlane(xzPlane, target);

// `target` now contains the world-space coordinates of the mouse-cursor
```

This handles detecting mouse-motion in the whole scene up to the horizon. Now if you want to support other movement-directions, you need to configure the `xzPlane` differently, for instance by computing the movement-plane in the mousedown-handler.

Also have a look at the [`TransformControls`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/TransformControls.js) that come with three.js, might already be what you're looking for: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=trans#misc_controls_transform

Another note: mousemove events typically fire out-of-sync with the animation-loop and may occur much more often than rendering. It is generally desirable to put all expensive operations like raycasting into the main animation-loop and only store the last seen mouse-position in the handler of the mousemove event. But this is probably just a minor issue that doesn't contribute much to the problem you are seeing.

Comment: I use a lager plane,and it works well,but I am puzzled by this:
```
var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 50, 50, 2, 2 );
   
```
TransformControls used a small plane ,and even the mouse leaves the plane,the object  still move.(PS:sorry,my native language isnt English,so  maybe it will be hard to understand  what i say,but i really try to  make it better)

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't follow. Where did you find that?

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/TransformControls.js  。
` //// PLANES

   var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 50, 50, 2, 2 );`

Comment: sorry, I haven't read the transform-controls implementation myself yet. No idea why that works better than in your case.